# Why do $\sum_i X_i Y_i$ and $\sum_i X_i \times i$ have the same distribution?

Tags: probability

This is a question from a class note of old times.

Suppose $X_i, i=1,\dots,n$ are iid random variables with pmf $P(X_i = 1) = P(X_i=-1) = 1/2$.

$(Y_i)_{i=1,\dots,n}$ is a $n$-dim random vector,  which takes values by all permutations of $1, \dots, n$, i.e. $Y_i$'s must take distinct values  from $1, \dots, n$.

$X_i, i=1,\dots,n$ and independent  of $Y_i, i=1,\dots,n$.

Why do $\sum_i X_i Y_i$ and $\sum_i X_i \times i$ have the same distribution?

If the iid $X_i$'s have a distribution $P(X_i = a) = p$ and $P(X_i=b) = 1-p$ for some $p \in [0,1]$, will $\sum_i X_i Y_i$ and $\sum_i X_i \times i$ still have the same distribution?

What is the more general conclusion from this example? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To try to answer your first and third questions: The general fact being used here is that, since the $X_i$s are i.i.d., they are exchangeable, i.e., for all permutations $\pi$ of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, the joint distributions of $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ and $(X_{\pi^{-1}(1)},\dots,X_{\pi^{-1}(n)})$ are the same.  Therefore, for all permutations $\pi$ of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, the distributions of $\sum_i X_i i$ and $\sum_i X_{\pi^{-1}(i)} i=\sum_i X_i \pi(i)$ are also the same.  Averaging over $\pi$, this means that if $(Y_1,\dots,Y_n)$ is a permutation-valued random variable which is independent of $X_1$, $\dots$, $X_n$, then $\sum_i X_i Y_i$ and $\sum_i X_i i $ have the same distribution.  So, the answer to your second question is yes: the $X_i$s can have an arbitrary distribution, as long as they are i.i.d. and independent of $Y_1$, $\dots$, $Y_n$, and the two distributions you mention will still be equal.  It is also possible that the $X_i$s could be exchangeable and independent of $Y_1$, $\dots$, $Y_n$ without being i.i.d., in which case the two distributions you mention will also still be equal.